# What does $qqro means appended after methodname in stacktrace of Delhi application

Tags: delphi

I have a created a stacktrace dump, using JCLDebug unit.
Can anybody tell me what the $qqro means, appended to the method name CheckValidDate?

> sToolEdit.TsCustomDateEdit.CheckValidDate$qqro (Line 926, "sToolEdit.pas" + 33) [00943068] sToolEdit.TsCustomDateEdit.CMExit$qqrr27Winapi.Messages.TWMNoParams (Line 960, "sToolEdit.pas" + 1)
>   [0055C3ED] Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc$qqrr24Winapi.Messages.TMessage (Line 7224, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91)
>   [0057FE70] Vcl.StdCtrls.Stdctrls.TButtonControl.WndProc$qqrr24Winapi.Messages.TMessage

(the above quote is only a clipped part of the whole stacktrace)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591030/delphi-unmangle-names-in-bpls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [mangled names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). The annotation of the name encodes the parameter lists and is used to disambiguate overloaded methods in runtime packages.

The is some useful information here: [Delphi - unmangle names in BPL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591030/delphi-unmangle-names-in-bpls)

Comment: So `qqro` means: `register calling convention, boolean`. etc.